# how to calculate time between two datetime in python?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have two datetime as below

```
start=2023/04/05 08:00:00, end=2023/04/05 16:00:00
```

I want to get time by

```
lTime = start + (end - start) /3 or 
lTime = (start * 2 + end) /3
```

I used code as below

```
lTime = start + timedelta(end - start) / 3
```

but I got error, what can I do?

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Comment: Can you make this a fully running example? There is something wrong with how you assigned `end` but you don't show how you did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using `datetime` objects to do this calculation.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start_str = '2023/04/05 08:00:00'
end_str = '2023/04/05 16:00:00'

start = datetime.strptime(start_str, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
end = datetime.strptime(end_str, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

lTime = start + (end - start) / 3
```

Comment: I said not clear, my date is still in datetime object.

Comment: Can you please provide a  MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're right! two datetime can be calculated.